# Grouping and sorting of elements

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class RebarUnique
{
    public Rebar MRebar { get; set; }
    public Point2d Point2d { get; set; }
}

public class Rebar
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public int Fi { get; set; }
}
```

I have list:

```
List<RebarUnique> rebarUnique;

[{{Number: 1, Type: 1, Fi: 12}, (0,0)},

{{Number: 1, Type: 1, Fi: 12}, (0,10)},

{{Number: 2, Type: 1, Fi: 12}, (15,18)},

{{Number: 3, Type: 1, Fi: 12}, (25,34)},

{{Number: 1, Type: 1, Fi: 12}, (25,34)},

{{Number: 3, Type: 1, Fi: 12}, (13,38)}]
```

I would like to get a list:

- group by `Number`
- sort by `Point2d` (`Y coordinate`)
- return a list (`Number`) with the lowest `Y coordinate`

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Tor  `List<RebarUnique> rebarUniqueL = rebarUnique.OrderByDescending(z => z.RebarUnique.Number).GroupBy(x => x.RebarUnique.Number).Select(c => c.First()).ToList();`But it does not work

Comment: return a list (Number) with the lowest Y coordinate - that means, for each group Number, you want a point2d with lowest Y ?

Comment: So why not just try this, and show us what you tried and why that didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
var rebarUniqueL = rebarUnique
    .GroupBy(x => x.MRebar.Number)
    .Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.Point2d.Y).First())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rebarUnique.OrderBy(x => x.Point2d.Y) // Order the items by Y
    .GroupBy(x => x.MRebar.Number) //Then group them by number, within each group the items are still sorted by Y
    .Select(g => new {Number = g.Key, Item = g.First()) // get lowest Y for each number
    .ToList();
```

Output:

```
Number   Item    
1        {{Number: 1, Type: 1, Fi: 12}, (0,0)}
2        {{Number: 2, Type: 1, Fi: 12}, (15,18)}
3        {{Number: 3, Type: 1, Fi: 12}, (25,34)},
```